# Count only the class name after the <ul id="pages">

Tags: jquery

I have this code in my page:

```
       <div id="content_1" class="select_more">
        <div>Name: <input type="text" name="fullname"/></div>
        <div>Age: <input type="text" name="age"/></div>
        <div>Address: <input type="text" name="address"/></div>
    </div>

    <ul id="my_tabs">
        <a href="javascript:select_page('2_');">page 1</a>
        <a href="javascript:select_page('3_');">page 2</a>
        <a href="javascript:select_page('4_');">page 3</a>
    </ul>
    <div id="content_2" class="select_more">
        <h3>Page 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content_3" class="select_more">
        <h3>Page 2</h3>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content_4" class="select_more">
        <h3>Page 3</h3>
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</p>
    </div>
```

I have this code in my jquery:

```
    jQuery('.select_more').each(function() {
        pageId = this.id.replace('content_', '');
    });
```

I only need to pick up select_more classes after the . The select_more class before the  should be ignored in my foreach. Currently, it picks up all select_more classes in the page.

I tried doing this but this didn't work too. It still counts all select_more in the pages.

```
    if( jQuery('ul#my_tabs').length )
    {
    jQuery('.select_more').each(function() {
        pageId = this.id.replace('content_', '');
    });
     }
```

Comment: What's wrong with :after ? http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
jQuery('ul#my_tabs').nextAll('.select_more').each(function() {
    pageId = this.id.replace('content_', '');
});
```

This will select all sibling elements after the `ul#pages` that match the `.select_more` selector.

http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

**Note:** In the HTML you posted there is only `<ul id="my_tabs">` not `<ul id="pages">` so make sure the correct `id` is used.

Comment: sorry, thats my fault. that should be my_tabs, i already edited it

Answer (score 2):

I believe the easiest choice is

> $("#my_tabs ~ .select_more")

please see jQuery selectors
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DSelectors%26redirect%3Dno

this works in jsbin

Comment: +1: A very elegant and simple solution. And the Sizzle selector engine (at least the one included with the latest jQuery version) makes sure the `~` general siblings selector works on IE6+ (which is normally not supported through CSS).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('ul#my_tabs').nextAll().filter(".select_more");
```